Historically, when were the terrestrial planets first called terrestrial planets?
I asked this on the Astronomy Stack Exchange, but it's probably better suited here—When did we start using the phrase "terrestrial planets" to refer to the inner planets in English scientific writing? Wikipedia offers "telluric planets" as well, but gives no indication of the history of the term: is that the earlier term?

I am not a historian, but I would guess around the same time we realized that the outer four planets were not terrestrial.

the comment by controlgroup suggests that would have been about the time that it was realized the outer planets are much different from the inner planets. And I have asked a question about when that happened. https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14083/when-was-it-realized-that-the-giant-planets-do-not-have-solid-surfaces Also see: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions

Google Ngram Viewer "terrestrial planets" and screenshot

The earliest publication I could find that uses the term terrestrial planets in the modern sense is an augmented English translation of François Arago's Leçons d'astronomie:
F. Arago, Popular lectures on astronomy. New York, Greely & McElrath 1845.
The additions by Dionysius Lardner in this publication are marked with an asterisk. In one of the marked sections in the sixth lesson, one finds on p. 39:

The four planets, Mercury, Venus, the Earth and Mars, present so many points of resemblance and mutual analogies, and differ in so many respects from the other planets, that they are sometimes regarded as a distinct class and called the Terrestrial Planets. They have the same order of magnitude, the same days and nights, are similar in their geographical character, are diversified by climates and zones, are supplied with atmospheres and clouds, and are theatres for the same play of meteorological phenomena. These form a body of circumstantial evidence which justify the conclusion that they are inhabited globes, in all respects similar to the earth.

I verified that there is no equivalent section in the original French edition (Paris 1836) nor in the contemporary German translation (Weimar 1838). It is not clear whether Lardner himself coined the modern sense of the term. In any event it seems to have caught on, because just two years later it appeared in a book for use in schools by the pedagogical writer John Stevens Cabot Abbott:
John S. C. Abbott, The young astronomer; or, The facts developed by modern astronomy, New York: J.C. Riker 1847.
On p. 50:

The four planets, Mercury, Venus, the Earth and Mars, are frequently called terrestrial planets. They are so called because they so much resemble each other.

